# Resetting / Reordering KEYS for array in actionscript

Tags: arrays, actionscript, flex4

I'm using Flex And I have created an array to feed into a datagrid, here is a small piece. I have deleted certain elements of the array, and now it is showing up with spaces in between non-deleted elements on the datagrid. I simply want to reorder the KEYS (not the elements themselves) of the array, so it will show up without spaces on the datagrid.

```
        [Bindable]  
        public var initDG:ArrayCollection;
        public function loaderComplete(event: Event):void {
                var fileString:String = event.target.data;
                var dataArray:Array = fileString.split("\n");
                var gridArray:Array = new Array();
                    for(var i:int = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {

                        var valueArray:Array = dataArray[i].split(",");
                        gridArray.push({PON:valueArray[0], VER:valueArray[1], DATE:valueArray[2], XML:valueArray[3], 
                              DOC:valueArray[4], SENT:valueArray[5]});


                    }

            var verizonArray:Array = gridArray;

            for(i = 0; i < verizonArray.length; i++) {
                var myPattern:RegExp = /^6006/;   
                var result:Object = myPattern.exec(verizonArray[i]["PON"].toString());
                if(result == null) {
                    delete verizonArray[i];
                }
            }

            // here I need to reorder the keys

            gridArray.shift();
            initDG=new ArrayCollection(verizonArray);

        }
```

**TL;DR: How to reset the keys of an array in actionscript looking like [0] => 'value', [3] => 'value', [6] => 'value' to [0] => 'value', [1] => 'value', [2] => 'value' without reordering the array itself**

Answer (score 0):

Yeah figured it out. To where I filter the array with the RegExp, I added this:

```
                if(result == null) {
                    delete verizonArray[i];
                } else {
                    countVerizonPons++;
                }
```

Therefore I have the number of actual elements in the array, then I sorted it to put all the empty elements at the bottom:

```
verizonArray.sortOn("DATE");
```

then I set the length to the number of actual elements:

```
verizonArray.length = countVerizonPons;
```

the end

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep the key position number you might find it easier to use:

```
array.splice(itemNumToRemove, numOfElementsToRemoveFromThatPosition)
```

In your code it would be:

```
if(result == null) {
     verizonArray.splice(i, 1)
}
```

Comment: Yeah this wouldn't work for me, no clue why, but it's what I tried first. It would just return the whole array as empty. Thank you for the answer